# Opening up a new page using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-table to render a table inside of my react webpage.

I added a link in the table cells to open up a new page like this:

```
Header: 'Game Title',
accessor: 'title',
Cell: ({ row }) => <a href={"gameDetails?id=" + row.original.id} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{row.original.title}</a>
```

When rendered, the link looks like this:

```
<a href="gameDetails?id=5" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Swords and Sabers</a>
```

Then the code for that gameDetails.js page looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function formatGame(game) {
    return game.gameName+ ' ' + game.gameGenre;
}

const game = {
    gameName: 'Swords and Sabers',
    gameGenre: 'RPG'
};

const element = (
    <h1>
        Game: {formatGame(game)}
    </h1>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But when it opens the new browser window, it's just the same react table, nothing is different except the URL which looks like this:

```
https://localhost:44376/gameDetails?id=5
```

How do I link to a new react page using href?

Thanks!

Comment: So are you using a router or something to render different pages?

Comment: when you don't set domain it open url from what is it now. So here open localhost.if you want to open page from another site you have to set domain completely and if it is in your react app you have to use react-router-dom for setting your pages.

Comment: @epascarello no I just want to open a link to a new page and pass the ID.  Thanks

Comment: @BeHappy it's just another site on my domain.  Links are so simple in HTML, why would we need to use a different library just to create a simple link?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell if page is in your react project, I mean page is another react component, you can use `react-router-dom` library. so you have to create a component for your page and set `Route` with this library.

Comment: @BeHappy but it is opening the new tab but with the original table component.  In the new tab, I don't need the table component, just some basic text regarding the game.  So maybe there's a way to 'erase' the current component?